# Where do the widget settings get saved on the Wordpress db?

Tags: wordpress

I want to backup the settings for the widgets on a WP blog. I took a look at the DB but I can't find where they are located. If you could provide some insight, it would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are saved as serialized values in wp_options. Their option names are prefixed with "widget_"

Answer (score 1):

All is in the database but more configurations of the Widgets are in serialized format.
To change the reference on serialized data there is some scripts, i use this that work fine.

link to download the script:
http://davidcoveney.com/575/php-serialization-fix-for-wordpress-migrations/